# dmesg to find usb key in Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, usb, logs

What exactly I must look for after a dmesg comand to find usb key? there are lots of entries with usb in them but which one?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I need the device nameof my usb so I can install Debian on it.

Comment: ... run `lsblk -no name,label,tran` before and after inserting your key

Comment: @don_crissti lsblk worked, thanks, just need to see where it is in dmesg.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
tail -f /var/log/dmesg
```

This will output the contents of `dmesg` as it happens. While you have this running, plug your USB memory stick in and note what it says. If you get heaps of non-related stuff, try this:

```
tail -f /var/log/dmesg | grep USB
```

This will only show lines containing the word USB. Use `Ctrl + C` to exit.

There is another answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/37775/203540) to a related question.

Comment: Note however that grepping will remove all context that doesn't contain the word USB (in caps), and often this context is important. Once you've identified the place where interesting things happen, always look at the complete dmesg output at the appropriate place. (`less` has a search function).

Comment: You are right: `less` is a much better way if you need to keep context information.

Answer (score 0):

You can start monitoring  the `dmesg` with the following command (You don't need to be root):

```
watch "dmesg | tail -5"
```

Then connect your USB device , the new entry will be displayed on the terminal.

Comment: Why use `watch` (executes every 2 seconds) instead of `tail -f` (executes when the output changes)?

Comment: @dirkt You should be root to access the log file `/var/log/`

Comment: So use `sudo`. You are doing admin work, you need root access, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In openSUSE systems (and some others) there is an `lssci` command that shows the disks with some short description, like this:

```
> lsscsi 
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD20EZRZ-00Z 0A80  /dev/sda 
[1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD20EZRZ-00Z 0A80  /dev/sdb 
[2:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  HL-DT-ST BD-RE  BH10LS30  1.01  /dev/sr0 
[3:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      HGST HTS541010A9 A560  /dev/sdc 
[4:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      HGST HTS541010A9 A560  /dev/sdd 
[6:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  Linux    File-CD Gadget   0404  /dev/sr1 
[7:0:0:0]    disk    SanDisk  Ultra Fit        1.00  /dev/sde
```